# git merge or git pull --rebase?

Tags: git

I'm facing the following problem: I have three branches called `product`, `toto` and `bms`. I want to push some modification on `product` (which is the parent of `toto` and `bms`) and I want to push the same modification from `product` to `toto` and `bms` without destroying all the rest of the code on those branch.

What command should I use?

Comment: You could use either, depending on your circumstances.

Comment: Either merge product to the other branches, or rebase them to product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you pushed changes to the product. To get that changes propagated to other branches you can do following

- Merge toto branch with product branch.
- Merge bms branch with product branch

Above merge will generate a merge commit locally that needs to be pushed to the remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

You could do either without destroying the rest of your code on the branch. You may have to resolve some conflicts, in either rebasing or merging, if you made modifications in the same place.

Rebase will place your commits above the other branch's commits.

Merge will create a new merge commit.

When you resolve the conflicts while rebasing or merging, you may choose the code that is correct.

Comment: So basically if I use the following commands :

git checkout toto && git rebase product
All the commit I made on "product" will be pushed on "toto" without fusionning "toto" and "product" ?